# CMOS Configuration For Bootable USB

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, usb, bios

I have a fit-pc (a small Linux box from 2007) running Ubuntu 8.04.  I want to upgrade to the newest Ubuntu Server distribution.  To do this, I've created a bootable USB using Rufus for that specific distro.

When I plug in the USB, the USB isn't recognized automatically on startup (no option to boot the distribution on the USB).  I was reading online and an article suggested changing the boot order (through CMOS configuration) so that the USB would boot first.  I changed the BIOS' default settings to the following:

DRIVE ASSIGNMENT ORDER: 
Drive A-B: (None)
Drive C: USB Hard Drive
Drive D-F: (None)

BOOT ORDER 
Boot 1st: Drive C:
Boot 2nd: (None)
Boot 3rd: (None)

After changing the settings, I selected "Write to CMOS and Exit".  After saving the settings, when I try booting, the following message is displayed, "No bootable device available".

Are there any other settings that I need to change in order to use the bootable USB?

Comment: Likely reason: bootable USB isn't made properly, or is in a format that's not understood by the fit-pc. Make sure not to use UEFI, if the stick is partitioned make sure partition is bootable, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem.  The bootable USB was set up properly.  However, in the BIOS, Drive C: needs to be set to NAND device, instead of USB.  For some reason, Drive D: didn't work.